# get number of files & file lines checked in by a user in git

Tags: git

i want to know how many number of newfiles checked in with the line count & number of modified lines in a existing files by an user in a GIT .. is ther any command or any existing reference please..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

```
# filter by author, display on one line with a short status
git log --author="name" --oneline --shortstat
```

This is the output of `--shortstat`
[image]

And this is the output of a full stats '--stat'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git fame](https://github.com/oleander/git-fame-rb) or `git log` + `awk`: `git log --author="Name" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | awk '{ add += $1; rm += $2; } END { printf "added lines: %s\nremoved lines: %s\n", add, rm}' -`

If you want to have stats per file, you can use a $(git ls-files) to do a loop: `for i in`git ls-files`; do echo $i; git log --author="Name" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | awk '{ add += $1; rm += $2; } END { printf "added lines: %s\nremoved lines: %s\n", add, rm}' -; done`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I tried with this command -  "git log --author="name" --pretty="%H" --pretty=tformat: --numstat" :: This gives me list of files changed per revision.

"git log --author="name" --pretty="%H" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | gawk '{ add += $1 ; subs += $2 ; loc += $1 - $2 } END { printf "added lines: %s removed lines : %s total lines: %s\n",add,subs,loc }'" :: This gives me total number of lines added/removed.

I need like a with respect to file count .. as format of "files.py total lines:12 / files2.py total lines:12.."